# Android, Service and client (activity) are running on different process. two-way communication using aidl

Tags: android, service, aidl

I am using aidl interface for IPC communication. After binding to service, I am able to call a API call from client to server.
But how do I send event from server to client using aidl?
Service and client are running on different process.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an `Intent` to the client from the `Service` when there is a event.

Another option could be to just poll each few seconds through aidl asking if there are new events.

And I think that you can send a [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) through AIDL (since it's Parcelable), so you can pass a Messenger to the service, and use it on the service to comunicate with the Activity.